# Graph Theory: Prove Ramsey Number $R(3, 4)=9$

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory

Most of the proofs I've seen prove this by showing that $R(3, 4) \leq 9$ and at the same time $\geq 9$. The former one is natural and easy to understand. To prove $R(3, 4) \geq 9$, a lot of proofs construct a graph with $8$ vertices which contains no $K_4$ and whose complement contains no $K_3$. The counterexample is often like
[this counterexample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGvV4.png).

As far as I know, $R(m, n)=R(n, m)$, so if I want to show that $R(3, 4) \geq 9$, the graph I construct should not contain any monochromatic $K_3$ or $K_4$. Go back to the counterexample. Though there is no blue $K_4$ and red $K_3$, it can be easily found that there are blue $K_3$s in the first graph. Is the counterexample wrong? Or is there any problem with my understanding about Ramsey Number? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The counterexample for $ R(3,4) > 8 $ need not be the same counterexample for $ R(4, 3) > 8 $. We could, through a series of transformations (like swapping the colors of the edges), get from one to the other. Though, there could be a lot of counterexamples for $R(3,4) > 8$ which may not relate to all of the counterexamples for $R(4,3) > 8$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The counterexample is correct. Note it's not the graph itself not containing $K_n$ and $K_m$:

If we say $R(n,m) = k$, then this means **every** graph $G$ with $k$ vertices, either $G$ contains a $K_n$ or the complement $G'$ contains a $K_m$. If we want to show $R(n,m) > k$, then we show that there exists **some** graph $G$ with $k$ vertices that fails that condition, namely $G$ does not contain $K_n$ **and** $G'$ does not contain $K_m$. We just need to find one such example.

Since in the counterexample you found, the 8-vertex graph $G$ (blue) has no $K_4$ and its complement $G'$ (red) contains no $K_3$, we see that $R(4,3)>8$. Now it is true that $R(4,3)=R(3,4)$: To show $R(3,4)>8$ as well, notice the graph $G'$ (red) has no $K_3$ and its complement $G''=G$ (blue) has no $K_4$.